# Bird in Taipei knocking on the window glass - juvenile hawk? white throat, white beak(?) striped breast, black head(?) brownish body(?), not small

Tags: species-identification, ornithology

I received these photos from a friend today - a slightly larger than average size bird tapping on the window glass; maybe a brownish body with a white throat and white beak and black head.

The tail is spread in a fairly wide fan, maybe to scare "the other bird" reflected in the window?

There's a front view and one with its head turned, but it's a little tricky to be sure of the colors since the sun is (roughly) behind the bird. I suppose it's possible that the beak may not be white, but just smooth and shiny and reflecting the sunshine.

Taken on a sunny, hot July afternoon in July in Taipei. Coat hangars for scale suggest it's a bit larger than the typical bird.

It reminds us somewhat of a Chinese Bulbul, but those distinct vertical stripes between its throat and breast are very distinctive.

It looks scary/predatory, could it be a juvenile hawk?

Chinese Bulbul photos (mostly from Hong Kong):

- https://nhillgarth.com/2013/10/25/more-birds-in-taiwan/
- https://cms.hkbws.org.hk/cms/en/hkbws/work/resarch/hk-bird-atlas-2020-en
- http://birdingtaiwan.blogspot.com/p/idiots-guide.html

Light-Vented Bulbul (also Hong Kong)

- https://theworldsrarestbirds.com/birds/birds-in-hong-kong/

[image: larger than average sized bird tapping on the window glass on a sunny, hot July afternoon in Taipei]

[image: larger than average sized bird tapping on the window glass on a sunny, hot July afternoon in Taipei]

[image: larger than average sized bird tapping on the window glass on a sunny, hot July afternoon in Taipei]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The light-vented bulbul looks quite promising, but I think this bird looks less song-birdy - the size and the large beak makes me think probably not.

I think the Taiwan scimitar-babbler (Pomatorhinus musicus) is the most promising.
you can check out this gallery: https://media.ebird.org/catalog?taxonCode=taiscb1&sort=rating_rank_desc&mediaType=photo

This bird shares the black stripe over the eyes, the thick and slightly curved beak, the breast feathers, the white stripe of feathers just above the eyes, the black feathers on the top of the head, and I think even the orange shoulder feathers if you look closely in the first image.

Comment: This seems inescapably correct, WOW! What a perfect fit. Both ebird's [taiscb1](https://ebird.org/species/taiscb1) and Wikipedia's [Taiwan scimitar babbler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taiwan_scimitar_babbler) say that it's "endemic to Taiwan" and the ebird map shows only sightings all over the main Taiwan island - from coastal to mountains, and the island(s) of Penghu - I'm just curious, is it really never, ever sighted outside of Taiwan?

Comment: I mean, I wouldn't say its absolutely NEVER seen outside of Taiwan, but when it comes to its natural range, endemic would mean that, yes, it is only found in there. According to <https://avibase.bsc-eoc.org/species.jsp?avibaseid=A37AFA6B7625915F> , this species used to be considered a subspecies of a related species found elsewhere in Asia and in fact right next to Taiwan in China, the streak-breasted scimitar babbler.

Comment: Interesting! [As of August 2005, there are at least 13 recognized subspecies of Pomatorhinus ruficollis.  In Taiwan, the song is lower-pitched with 3–4 upturned notes on the same pitch.  P. r. stridulus. which inhabits hill forests of southeast China (Guandong, Fujian and Jiangxi), is the nearest population to Taiwan.](https://www.birdingintaiwan.com/scimitar-babbler.htm)